# Android Studio 3.1.2 hangs after opening a project

Tags: android-studio

[image]

I have been facing this problem after installing the 3.1.2 version of Android Studio in my Windows 10 Education 32-bit laptop.

Comment: is there space available in your installation drive

Comment: Yes, enough space!